# Per-item/home screen-like scroll

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to implement a vertical scrolling for an bunch of elements so that each element occupies most of the screen. It's analog is a horizontal scroll on most, I guess, home screens, which you use when locating between those screens.

So far, I just made a listview, but I need somehow to fix row count per screen(1). Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try [this](https://github.com/grantland/android-verticalpager)? It is a VerticalPager (I think the name is pretty self-describing).

Comment: It might be it ! Let me test it first. To be honest I had forgotten about pagers when approached this issue :)